# indicator-messages absent in 13.04 fresh install

Tags: unity, indicator, indicator-message

I can't find a way to show the "blue mail" indicator

What I think :

- this indicator is called "indicator-messages"
- Ubuntu change some things (like removing the whitelist)

I tried :

- to reinstall indicator-messages package
- multiple reboots
- to create another account (if there was specific configuration I made in ~/.config)

What I have done :

- installed aptitude
- `aptitude update && aptitude upgrade`
- fresh install Ubuntu 13.04 amd64
- uninstall all packages with ubuntuone (with automatic dependencies)
- configure twitter account (settings -> online accounts)
- installed gwibber
- reboot

  `$ uname -a
  Linux Antsirabe 3.8.0-23-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 20:22:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Thanks for your time!

Comment: First try run a application which uses messaging-menu like empathy, Thunderbird, etc. Perform update through update-manager as fresh install of Ubuntu use to have lots of bugs.

Comment: I always do `aptitude update && aptitude upgrade` (after installing aptitude of course). I just tried to add twitter account (seems working) but the icon didn't appear

Comment: Which application you are using with twitter?

Comment: I am not sure, I opened empathy => configure, which open the same as System settings => online accounts

Comment: Empathy is for chat. Configure a chat account (gtalk, jabber). OR add a gmail-account in thunderbird. Gwibber or Friends-app are for twitter. Both of them are `NOT` installed by default. So even if you add twitter on UOA, there is still no application to use it with messaging menu.

Comment: gwibber installed, reboot, no icon :'(

Comment: In 13.04 Gwibber is a dummy package. It actually installs friends- app. But friends-app not integrated to messaging menu (yet).

Answer (score 4):

`Indicator-Messages` appears only when there is a application to use with it, i.e. When application registers itself to messaging-menu & (sync-menu).

Thunderbird by-default uses indicator messages.

- So after fresh install just launch thunderbird & configure a mail account.
- Indicator messages WILL appear in unity-panel.

**OR**

you can manually add application(desktop file) to messaging-menu from dconf-editor:

- Launch `dconf-editor` from dash
- go to `com.canonical.indicator.messages`
- If its empty, add applications manually (`thunderbird.desktop`, `evolution.desktop`, `friends-app.desktop` etc.) as shown in the picture below:

[image]

**DONE!**

Comment: the second part is very instructive in general. Thanks for the tip!